# Enable user to fill in data

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to enable user to pick up a file from a given year/ month etc. and bring data into the file I'm working on.

For this, I've created a "Parameters" sheet where I've labelled the cells "Year" and "Month". When I put these variables in the code, it triggers error.
I believe I'm declaring Y and Z incorrectly, and also concatenating it poorly into the last line. I tested the code without Y/Z variables and actual file location and it works.

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim Y As String
Dim Z As String
Y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Cells("Year")
Z = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Cells("Month")
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("W:\01-Forecasts\&Y&\Monthly Forecast\&Z&\File.xlsm")
```

Comment: `labelled the cells` does this mean you made them named ranges?  and if so are their scope worksheet or workbook?

Comment: I went to the cell's location i.e. B2 and changed the title of it to "Year" so that when you click on B2, it displays "2017" and title is "Year" instead of B2.

Comment: The nomenclature is `Named` not `Titled`.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help. I'm new to most of this. Any tips to improve the case above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Range` not `Cells()`

And all vba variables need to be outside the quotes and concatenated with `&`

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim Y As String
Dim Z As String
Y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("Year")
Z = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("Month")
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("W:\01-Forecasts\" & Y & " \Monthly Forecast\" & Z & "\File.xlsm")
```

Comment: @user8958702 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.